# Probability - exponential distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I got the following question:

There are two cashiers in a supermarket, the waiting time for each is of exponential distribution with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ accordingly.
Person 1 arrives at cashier 1 at 9:00.
Person 2 arrives at cashier 2 at 9:01.
Person 3 arrives at 9:03 with both cashiers still being occupied, and flips a fair coin by which he decides to wait for cashier 1 or 2 (after choosing a cashier, he is only waiting for that one).
If it is known that at 9:06, his turn still hasn't arrived yet, what is the probability that at 9:08 it still wouldn't be his turn?

I tried to solve it this way:
Y = overall waiting time for person 3

X = 1 if cashier 1 was chosen, 0 else

$P(Y > 3+2 | Y > 3) = P(Y > 2) = P(Y > 2 | X = 1) \cdot P(X = 1) + P(Y > 2 | X = 0) \cdot P(X = 0 ) = e^{-2\lambda_1} \cdot 0.5 + e^{-2\lambda_2} \cdot 0.5$

Apparently my solution is wrong but I don't understand why. If you could please point to where I'm mistaken and how could it be solved correctly that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

When you write $P(Y>3+2 \mid Y>3) = P(Y>2)$, you assume that $Y$ is a memoryless distribution: an exponential. But $Y$ is not an exponential: $Y$ is the mixture of two exponentials with different rates! So we can't make this simplification yet.

Instead, consider the following four cases:

- $X=1$ and $3 < Y < 5$: this happens with probability $\frac12(e^{-3\lambda_1} - e^{-5\lambda_1})$.
- $X=1$ and $Y > 5$: this happens with probability $\frac12 e^{-5 \lambda_1}$.
- $X=2$ and $3 < Y < 5$: this happens with probability $\frac12(e^{-3\lambda_2} - e^{-5\lambda_2})$.
- $X=2$ and $Y > 5$: this happens with probability $\frac12 e^{-5 \lambda_2}$.

These are the probabilities *before* we are told that $Y>3$. But when we *are* given that $Y>3$, we know that exactly one of these four cases happens. So we should scale up these four probabilities so that they add up to $1$. They become, respectively:
$$
   \frac{e^{-3\lambda_1} - e^{-5\lambda_1}}{e^{-3\lambda_1} + e^{-3\lambda_2}},\;
   \frac{e^{-5\lambda_1}}{e^{-3\lambda_1} + e^{-3\lambda_2}},\;
   \frac{e^{-3\lambda_2} - e^{-5\lambda_2}}{e^{-3\lambda_1} + e^{-3\lambda_2}},\;
   \frac{e^{-5\lambda_2}}{e^{-3\lambda_1} + e^{-3\lambda_2}}.\;
$$
To get the probability that $Y>5$, we just want to add up the second and fourth case, getting
$$
   \frac{e^{-5\lambda_1} + e^{-5\lambda_2}}{e^{-3\lambda_1} + e^{-3\lambda_2}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd like to point out that the exponential distribution is not totally realistic for the time $1$ person takes to check out. It is memoryless, meaning that after a person waits $x$ minutes, the remaining time $y$ they'll need to wait is independent of $x$. $y$ will be the same whether $x$ is $1$ minute or $10$ minutes. So the "*If it is known that*" clause should be jumping out at you. At the outset, the exponential distribution can be used to *forecast* the time it will take for something to happen, but once some time has passed, the forecast changes.

If it is known that at 9:06, his turn still hasn't arrived yet, then that is $t=0$ for our equations. The probability that at 9:08 it still wouldn't be his turn is the inverse of the probability that it would be, which is the $\text{OR}$ junction of the two exponential distributions. (The $\text{OR}$ of two probabilities is their sum minus the probability of both occuring.)

$$Pr(X \leq 2 \text{ min}) = 1- e^{-(2/(\lambda_1 \text{in minutes}))} + 1- e^{-(2/(\lambda_2 \text{in minutes}))} - [(1- e^{-(2/(\lambda_1 \text{in minutes}))}) \cdot (1- e^{-(2/(\lambda_2 \text{in minutes}))})]$$

Comment: What you're not taking into account is that "at 9:06, his turn hasn't arrived yet" is information about which line he chose. For example, suppose that the first cashier is very fast and the second is very slow: $\lambda_1 = 100$ and $\lambda_2 = 0.01$. The information "at 9:06, his turn hasn't arrived yet" is strong evidence that he chose the second cashier, because this has an $e^{-300} \approx 0$ chance of happening with the first cashier.